# Removing folders from sync parternships in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync

A while back I set my computer up to sync folders on a shared network drive. I didn't choose my folders carefully and ended up with a huge amount of files to sync, which took forever.
I would like to stop sync on those folders, then later select some smaller subfolders to sync. I believe this means I first must delete the existing sync partnerships, but there is no "Delete" option when I list them in Sync Center.

How can I delete existing sync partnerships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the root folder of the sync relationship in Explorer, open its properties. In the Offline Files tab, untick the box.

Answer (score 2):

To end a sync partnership:

Open Sync Center by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Sync Center.

Right-click the sync partnership that you want to end, and then click Delete.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me, but may not require all the steps I did. This is for Windows 7.

1. Do the registry edit described by IAmConfused [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-cant-delete-a-partnership-in-windows-7-sync/bba7bc96-7763-4a22-ac9b-f3d58ec80da4). Reboot.
2. Go to [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/cant-remove-sync-partnership/13133688-7a7c-410a-a978-3d3d86f1c9b8) and follow CyMel's instructions for disabling Offline Files, reboot, then follow Marilyn O's instructions for changing permissions on the folder, then manually deleting the sync partnership. Reboot.
3. I then started new sync partnerships by right clicking on the (smaller) folders I wanted to sync, then choosing 'Make available offline'.
4. The initial sync of these new folders took over 24 hours without completing, so I checked and realized I was trying to sync over 40 GB of data.
5. I again deleted the syncs, selected my folders carefully so only the most essential were included, and the sync now completes fast.